# Loop Question Basic PHP - What kind of loop I need

Tags: php, loops

I have a function, so if is_page( 280 ) is true I want to call a php file with get_template_part( 'nav' ); .I can do it with if-else loop.But, after get the php file, my main php file continues read the below lines such as html etc.I dont want it.I want to stop read below lines if is_page( 280 ) is true.Also I want to develop same loop for different values.For example, if is_page( 999 ) is true and is_page( 280 ) is false, so now, call different php file and stop read below lines in main php.If all condition about is_page functions are false, so now read below lines in main php.

I know it is basic, I wait your helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable to stop the script if needed.

```
$stop_script = false;

if(is_page(280)===true){
  ... include file;
  $stop_script=true;
  }
else if(is_page(999)===true){
  ... include file;
  $stop_script=true;
  }

if($stop_script === true) die; //stop the script

//rest of php
```

Or simply `die` if a template is loaded:

```
if(is_page(280)===true){
  ... include file;
  die;
  }
else if(is_page(999)===true){
  ... include file;
  die;
  }
```